# omnifaces cause Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war - tomee

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf-2.2, omnifaces, apache-tomee

**I am using JSF + Spring + Hibernate** + **TomEE** my application is running well. as I am using primefaces 4.0 and decide to use omniface  [FullAjaxExceptionHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler). I did the following steps in my projects

1) Add factory in **faces-config.xml**

```
<factory>
 <exception-handler-factory>org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

click here to see my [faces-config.xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6g8bnw75fa7hnb/faces-config.xml?dl=0)

2) Add the follwing entries in **web.xml**

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/expired.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.sql.SQLException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/database.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/bug.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.omnifaces.showcase.exceptionhandlers.EpicFailException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/epicfail.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/400.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

click here to see my [web.xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9gy83iegex6qe7a/web.xml?dl=0)

3) Add dependency in **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

click this link to see my [pom.xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/22g5jzx8dkibmip/pom.xml?dl=0)

After that I run my server **TomEE**, it showing the following **exception in console**

```
 SEVERE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war  StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/vanter]
 org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Can't find resource for class com.vs.erp.dao.template.GenericDAOImpl#sessionFactory. (No provider available for resource-ref id with type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' for 'vanter.Comp1804974291'.)
at  org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef(AutoConfig.java:1153)
```

click to see exception in detail [Complete Console log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7fkj3lxv3m4z6zf/Complete%20Exception.txt?dl=0)

Click for [applicationContext.xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zlgt80abtlht4h4/applicationContext.xml?dl=0)

any **update** / **solution** , am I missing any thing ? and why omnifaces effecting the SessionFactory?

Comment: Which TomEE version? For 1.x you need OmniFaces 1.x and for 2.x you need OmniFaces 2.x. During our test runs on 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.7.1 and 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT we haven't encountered any problems. By the way, why Spring if TomEE as being a Java EE container already offers same features as Spring? (EJB, CDI, JTA, etc). You usually see Spring on a bare Tomcat as it isn't a Java EE container.

Comment: @BalusC `Issue Resolved` yeh its version mismatch , I was using omniface 2.x with TomEE 1.x. and yes `we usually see Spring on a bare Tomcat`. Actually in production we are using Tomcat 7.` Near future we may move to TomEE etc etc .. ..bhala bhala  :p ;) `Thanks BalusC for point out possible cause`